# Compute angle and radius of a circular segment

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I need some help computing the angle and radius of a (given) circular segment.

All I have is a start point $P_0 = (0,0)$ where the circular segment begins, at the origin. The length of circle arc curve of sector $b=40$ above x-axis, the y-coordinate of the top point of the arc of segment $y_{P_1}=24$.

I know that the mid-point of arc will be at $y_M=0$, so $x_M=r$.However, I do not know $r$.

As fas as I understand $P_2 = (x_{P_2},-24)$ may have second possible position will be
$-y$,  mirrored along the $x$-axis, with $x_1$ = $x_2$ kept same. That is, $y_{P_2}$ will be negative $ y_{P_1}$.

But so far I couldn't find or derive any formula using only one unknown.

Comment: Thanks for eddit, but the x-coordinate of p2 is not known and not x^2.

Answer (score 0):

Considering one half of the lines of the segment only, due to symmetry you mentioned:

$$ r \sin \theta = 24 $$
$$ r \, \theta = 40 $$

Dividing,

$$ \frac {sin(\theta)}{ \theta}=0.6 $$

This is a transcendental equation. $\theta$ can be found numerically approximately equal to 1.66 radians or 95 degrees more than a right angle 90 degrees.

Radius r can be computed from the second equation.